# Is the set where there is a unique distance minimizer to a submanifold open?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, and let $S \subseteq M$ be a compact submanifold.

Define $U=\{  p \in M \, | \, \text{there exist a unique closest point to } p \text{ in } S\}$. Is $U$ open in $M$?

Does the answer change if we assume that $M$ is complete or geodesically convex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Here's a counterexample. Let $M=\mathbb R^2$, and let $S$ be the ellipse defined by $x^2/4 + y^2 = 1$. For a point $p=(a,0)$ on the positive $x$-axis, a nice calculus exercise shows the following: As long as $0< a< 3/2$, there are two points on the ellipse closest to $p$, namely those points whose $x$-coordinate is $4a/3$. But for $3/2 \le a < 2$, the unique closest point to $p$ is $(2,0)$. In particular, $p=(3/2,0)$ has no neighborhood contained in $U$.

Comment: Thank you Professor Lee, this is a nice example. I wonder what was wrong with my initial thinking: I thought that the set of points in $M$ where there is a unique projection correspond to the image of the normal exponential map $\text{exp}:NS \to M$ on the domain where it is a diffeomorphism, which should be an open subset of $M$. Perhaps being more accurate, I should say that $U=\text{exp}(V)$ where $V$ is the subset  of $NS$ on which $\text{exp}$ is injective. **Edit:** I now see that $V$ is not necessarily open. Actually what I wrote here is somewhat vague and inaccurate.

Comment: My point is that the failure of the opennes should have an equivalent phrasing in terms of properties of the normal exponential map, which I don't see clearly at the moment.  Do you see such a thing? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the key is to look at the set where the (normal) exponential map is *locally* injective.

Comment: @AsafShachar: There's an analogue of the [cut locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) for submanifolds: A point $q\in M$ is a ***cut point*** for the submanifold $S\subseteq M$ if it's in the image of a normal geodesic $\gamma$ starting on $S$ which is minimizing before it hits $q$ and not minimizing after $q$. ...

Comment: I believe the following is true: If $q$ is the cut point for $S$ along $\gamma$, then either (a) there are two or more minimizing geodesics from $S$ to $q$, or (b) $q$ is a ***focal point*** of $S$, meaning it's a singular value of the normal exponential map. (It's also possible for both (a) and (b) to hold.) The case in which $S$ is a single point is proved in my *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* (2nd ed.), Proposition 10.32, and I think a very similar proof goes through for general $S$, though I haven't checked it. In the example I gave, the point $(2/3,0)$ is a focal point of $S$.